# non-linear first order PDE with analytic coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider   a linear first order PDE $f(x)u_x + g(y)u_y = F(u), u  = u(x,y)$, where $f(x)$, $g(y)$, $F(u)$ are analytic functions, is it safe to assume that all solutions to this PDE are analytic as well?

Comment: Since $F(u)$ is in general non-linear, this equation is non-linear.  I edited your title accordingly.  Cheers!